# Chaining mutiple queries to produce an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to be able to search my drinks by either the drink's name or the drinks ingredients.

```
def index
  @drinks2 = Drink.where(:ingredients => {:name => params[:search]}).joins(:ingredients)
  @drinks = @drinks2 + Drink.where(:name => params[:search])
end
```

My above solution works, but I'm looking for an improvement. This seems to be somewhat of a hack.

My question: Is there any way to combine these 2 queries into a single line? and is that the right way of going about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is both possible and fairly simple, but it does require writing some actual SQL - you can't rely on the hash-based conditions. Assuming you have an `ingredients` table with a `name` column:

```
@drinks = Drink.joins(:ingredients).where('drinks.name = :search OR ingredients.name = :search', :search => params[:search])
```

Comment: If you're using this often it might be a good candidate for a scope on the class.

Comment: While I'm with SQL, why wouldnt this work with the rails conditions? (Thanks for the answer btw, it works perfectly)

Comment: @BrianJakovich - So far as I know, when you use the Rails conditions hash, there's no way to tell it to return results that match ANY (rather than ALL) of the conditions. Rails assumes you want to join them with AND, rather than OR. There are some gems (Squeel - https://github.com/ernie/squeel , for instance) that let you get around this, but without them you seem to be stuck writing SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
Drink.where(:ingredients => {:name => params[:search]}, :name => params[:search] ).joins(:ingredients)
```

Comment: I would expect that to result in an AND - a drink that has the provided name *and* an ingredient with the searched name. I think to get OR, you need to either write out the SQL or use a gem that expands the search syntax.